# GUI Tool for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am new to **PostgreSQL** database and I want to know if there any **GUI Tools** for **PostgreSQL** just like **SQLYog** for **MySQL**?

Comment: Opensource alternative http://sqlectron.github.io/

Comment: Just seen it and found very fascinating. Will definitely try some day. Thanks for your precious comment

Comment: Good web gui: [jackdb](https://www.jackdb.com/) , but it's commercial

Comment: Check https://github.com/sosedoff/pgweb it's a single-binary and runs across platforms.

Comment: https://github.com/web-pal/DBGlass Just released Free, Open sourced, For any platform PostgreSQL GUI client.

Comment: EMS is good. Try it out http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/downloads

Comment: Big selection on https://github.com/dhamaniasad/awesome-postgres#gui list and https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Comment: http://dbglass.web-pal.com/ works for me!

Comment: I wonder if there gonna be one day when stackoverflow will allow best practises postings in here, like non-opinionated posts, like it presenting facts from some case-studies and so on.

Comment: Check out dbForge Studio for PostgreSQL! It is available to download it at https://www.devart.com/dbforge/postgresql/studio/download.html

Comment: Thanks I figured out how to use PGADMIN with docker image.

Comment: Tried [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) and it seems fine for me. This is basically an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: try Navicat Premium
https://navicat.com/en/products/navicat-premium

Answer (score 165, accepted):

There is a comprehensive list of tools on the PostgreSQL Wiki:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients

And of course PostgreSQL itself comes with [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/), a GUI tool for accessing Postgres databases.

Comment: I've been trying out pgAdmin, and frankly it seems terrible. I only have one database, and it takes me 6 clicks to open up my list of tables, then a right click and view in a separate window just to see the data in a table. I do not recommend it.

Comment: @CorayThan: I agree ;) (although I wouldn't call it "terrible") But I don't use pgAdmin either.

Comment: Perhaps "obtuse" would've been a better term! Functionally, it does seem fine.

Comment: Yeah, pgAdmin is disgusting. It's the common approach of "let's create a tool with a lot of resources that sucks to use". PhpPGAdmin is less worse but it's still not good.

Comment: The worst part is that the official release for Linux Mint.. pgadmin doesn't have a "disable autocommit feature" ... that the most ridiculous thing I've ever seen in a DB tool ever

Comment: @CorayThan Do you use any other free tool? What would you recommend?

Comment: Just downloaded v4.x. Is there a way to turn off these absolutely atrocious animations? Swooooop! - modal in - vvhoooOOOPP - modal out. 0/10 would uninstall again.

Comment: This "comprehensive list" has not been updated for a while.  [pgAdmin 4](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/) v1.0, which is not included, was released Sept. 29, 2016.

Comment: OMG I thought I was crazy... I installed and uninstalled PGAdmin twice because I just couldn't stand it, and updating constraints didn't work... It really is crap, how is it the most prolific GUI for Postgres?

Comment: As of May 2018 it is not too bad. Keep in mind that most here switch to Postgres from another database management system and tools, which they got used to, so new stuff feels awkward.

Comment: pgAdmin 4 is still quite unfriendly to use in August 2018. You have to navigate in (sub-)context menus even to do a simple SELECT; you cannot sort columns by just clicking on them, you have to open a popup for that; it even asks confirmation to remove a sort parameter! It might have improved compared to previous versions but it's still not recommended if you'd like to stay sane. I wish there was a free/libre GUI tool at the level of phpMyAdmin or Mysql Workbench

Answer (score 17):

Postgres Enterprise Manager from EnterpriseDB is probably the most advanced you'll find. It includes all the features of pgAdmin, plus monitoring of your hosts and database servers, predictive reporting, alerting and a SQL Profiler.

http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products/postgres-enterprise-manager

> Ninja edit disclaimer/notice: it seems that this user is affiliated with EnterpriseDB, as the linked Postgres Enterprise Manager website contains a video of one Dave Page.

Comment: "...and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."

Comment: EnterpriseDB doesn't have a single screenshot of the app. Dead giveaway it sucks.