# What are some good postgresql admin interfaces?

Tags: postgresql

Currently I use mysql and phpMyAdmin, I was wondering if there is as great a tool as phpmyadmin for postgresql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Desktop SQL clients for PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654987/desktop-sql-clients-for-postgresql)

Comment: possible duplicate of [GUI Tool for PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667264/gui-tool-for-postgresql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools has a list