# How can I change from SQLite database to PostgreSQL database in a working Rails project for localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite

in database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: demo_test_development
  pool: 5
  username: adarsh
  password: 
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: demo_test_test
  pool: 5
  username: adarsh
  password: 
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

in gem file

```
group :development do

    gem 'pg'
    gem 'taps'

end
```

then I do

1) Bundle install (is working)

2)rake db:setup,db:create,db:migrate(but is not working)

Getting error : could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
                      Couldn't create 'demo_test_development' database. Please check your configuration.

Comment: Please check if postgres service has started or not and have you installed postgresql in your system???and created a user named adarsh

Comment: no , pls tell me any good documentation.

Comment: which os are you using

Comment: postgresql setup on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Refer to this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: after installing create a user and restart postgres service

Comment: sumath it not working. i install postgres, when i type \du in console i get output = \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 adarsh    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

then i do restart postgres service... but 2 error =  no password supplied and
Couldn't create 'demo_test_development' database.

Comment: add a password to your user and place the same in database.yml file

Comment: Ya,I solve it, thanks for your help

Comment: sumanth best db browser for postgresql? like DB Browser for SQLite..

Comment: you can use pgadmin that comes with postgres can refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667264/gui-tool-for-postgresql

Comment: i already have data in rails application,i just want to pop out data in pgadmin,for that i want write any additional query.

Comment: Do you want to wipe the data from database???

Comment: no,in sqllite we just do for open database,
open database button/my Documents/app name/db/development.sqlite3 like that in pgadmin how can i open database?

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty You might want to make your guidance in these comments into an answer to help others more easily. Then, the answer can also be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install postgresql package into your system you can refer to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04) link for instruction regarding installing postgres all you need to do is execute the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

> this installs postgres into your system

then you need to create a user with the details that you have mentioned in the database.yml file of your rails application

You can use pgadmin for db browser you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667264/gui-tool-for-postgresql) question for other tools

to install pgadmin3 run the following command

```
 sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

then configure it with the details like host port etc that you are using(refer to database.yml)

Answer (score 0):

You are using gem 'pg' in development group in gem file.

```
group :development do

    gem 'pg'
    gem 'taps'

end
```

Include it in every environment by moving this line out of `development` group.

Comment: gd i solve that, now i am confusing with seup pgadmin...EX = in sqllite we just do for open database, open database button/my Documents/app name/db/development.sqlite3 like that in pgadmin how can i open database?

Comment: You need to add `New Server` under `file => Add Server`. There will be `localhost` in the list under the server. There you will find you `DB`.

Comment: ya i got it in place of localhost i add host num 127.0.0.1 it work thanks all, for helping me...........

Comment: Please accept the answer then to help others as well

Comment: @AdarshKL Only accept the answer if it solved your problem, it seemed that Sumanth contributed the most to solve your problem, maybe they will leave an answer based on their comments.